# How to design a typescript project for export

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

My apologies as I'm new to the js ecosystem. I'm working at a place that uses typescript which is great because it's helped me move from background of static languages. However I still don't understand the packaging/module system especially in conjunction with typescript definitions.

I'm writing a module with a bunch of interfaces describing web service API contracts, to be used by the client library and the API service itself. If this were C#/Java or something I would write my interface files, package it up, publish it and it would be consumed by saying

`import GetWizardsResponse from StuffInc.Contract.Wizards`

That was how I approached my typescript library, so I wrote

```
export interface GetWizardsResponse {
    wizards: Wizard
    currentPage: number
    count: number
}
```

Then in my `ts.config` I have `"declaration": true` so after `tsc` I get a `Wizards.d.ts` and `Wizards.js`. When I `npm publish` this I have to consume it by doing something like this:

`import {GetWizardsResponse} from '@StuffInc/contracts/Wizards'`

but when I look around it's more common to see imports like this:

`import * as Express from 'express'`

or

`import { Response, NextFunction } from 'express'`

so I take it using my package should look like:

`import { GetWizardsResponse } from '@StuffInc/contracts`

That way I can have `/wizards`, `/goblins`, `/elves` but the import is always from `from @StuffInc/contracts'. That's what I what (that's what I'm supposed to do right? All NPM packages look like that)

To do this I gather I need to put everything in a single `index.d.ts` file. Can I still write my code in logical separate files but have it build into one definition so that there's less guess work by other developers?

Comment: I got no hint when I use `export default xxx`, but `export xxx` works fine. I don't know why, I guess it's a bug, just don't use `export default` in TS anyway

Comment: I'm not too sure on what problem you're having but I can't help but notice you're not using any `;` or `,` anywhere in your `.ts` examples which I'm sure is causing tons of errors.  For example, the interface should look like `export interface GetWizardsResponse{ wizards: Wizard, currentPage: number, count: number }` using commas between each one. Then there's your imports which should look like `import{ GetWizardsResponse } from '@StuffInc/contracts/Wizards';` using a `;` at the end. If you can be more specific about what you're doing and show the code for `Wizards` I might be able to help.

Comment: @Optiq sorry, yes you're correct. I just free-handed the code in. My real code is more boring so I used purposely fanciful examples to make sure the focus in on the question. Although out project doesn't use `;` and the linter complains if you use them. Apparently they're optional. It's one of the many reasons I'm confused by this language, it's so fun to have multiple ways to do things

Answer (score 0):

You're very close, only thing your missing to get the pretty names is an index.ts with `export * from '@StuffInc/contracts/Wizards'`

The trick is that you can export something multiple times from different files.
Module loaders like webpack will know to look for an index.d.ts or a .d.ts named after your project (moment has a moment.d.ts).

Modules are kinda complicated in js/ts right now but with es6 modules becoming more normal its getting better. There are also things called default exports, they allow for `import package from 'package'` syntax. Tools like Moment that have a global namespace should use this, it also allow for named imports too. `import moment, { Duration } from 'moment'`. Not many modules are using defaults yet though, so you can't import from moment like that line. You would have to do this `import * as moment from 'moment'`. You will see this if they have a declared namespace instead of explicit exports/default. My point is that you want to stay away from * imports if you can, you will have to use them your importing a node module that doesn't have them setup but with explicit imports module bundlers can make you packages small with techniques like tree shaking and code splitting.

That's a quick brush up on what I've been able to figure out so far but I would do some more research into modules.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed overview. So I should aim to have `import { Wizard } from 'myModule' be possible to module clients can be more efficient? Makes sense. To do that I need an `index.d.ts` in the root of my module which somehow points to the `\wizards` or whatever other files?

Comment: yes. There are tools to generate definition files, so if your using webpack most ts loaders have an option to output definition files. tsc also had a `--declaration` flag that will generate the .d.ts file.